# CentOS6 and PostgreSQL-YUM, (Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: pgdg90. Please verify its path and try again)

Tags: centos, postgresql, yum, centos6

I'm using CentOS 6. I need to configure my YUM to have access to the PostgreSQL repository, but I'm getting an error.

I've followed this guide: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?/archives/45-An-Almost-Idiots-Guide-to-PostgreSQL-YUM.html

When I do:

```
yum install postgresql
```

I got this error:

```
[root@andre yum.repos.d]# yum install postgresql
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, rpm-warm-cache
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.di.fc.ul.pt
 * extras: ftp.di.fc.ul.pt
 * updates: ftp.di.fc.ul.pt
http://yum.pgsqlrpms.org/9.0/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: pgdg90. Please verify its path and try again
```

Someone have any clue on what I should do to correct this?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://yum.pgsqlrpms.org/ is not used anymore, they have relocated to pgrpms.org, this is causing your errors.

Revert your changes, then check http://yum.pgrpms.org/howtoyum.php, this page will tell you to install the CentOS 6 repository RPM from [here](http://yum.pgrpms.org/reporpms/repoview/pgdg-centos.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. What changes I need to revert? Uninstall pgdg-centos-9.0-2.noarch?

Comment: @André yes, also check that the `/etc/yum.repos.d` does not contain any more `.repo` files for postgres. Then install the new RPM

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've successfully installed PG9. But I van't install pgAdmon3. I have configured the Postgresql-yum maninly to install pgAdmin3, but I van't. Give me [root@andre yum.repos.d]# yum install pgadmin3
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, rpm-warm-cache
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.di.fc.ul.pt
 * extras: ftp.di.fc.ul.pt
 * updates: ftp.di.fc.ul.pt
Setting up Install Process
No package pgadmin3 available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: @André technically, that is a completely different question ;) there is a pgadmin3 package maintained in the EPEL repository, see http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

Comment: great! That link save my day in the PgAdmin installation. Thank you very much for your help.